# Using Config Transformation with external files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, web-config

I have a collection of web service and sites all installed on the same machine which share settings so I have put them in an external config file one folder above the application folders such as below.

```
<appSettings file="../common.config"/>
```

I see that with Config Transforms I can change individual values within this section had my settings been inside the appSettings block but is it possible to change the file attribute itself?

```
<appSettings file="../common_release.config"/>
```

or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config transforms are actually applied by Visual Studio upon building a deployment package; so there is no *_release* or *_debug* version in the output.

Of course, you could use what ever files you want for external configuration.

Comment: Right....so when deploying my applications, can it do what I asked in the question which is apply a transformation to the attribute rather than the values? Essentially deploying both config BUT having VS apply the transformation based on the build configuration.

Comment: Oh.. I see what you mean; have it applying the transform to the `file` attribute itself... duh! Yes; it absolutely can do that. The sample transform files have some good examples on it.